# Trace norm is independent of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, fourier-analysis, representation-theory

Is it true that the trace norm $$\operatorname{tr}(TT^*)$$ is independent of the inner product that the adjoint is being taken relative to? If this is not the case, then I am confused by the proof of Plancherel’s theorem in [https://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/randomwalksongroup.pdf](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ecgates/PERSI/papers/randomwalksongroup.pdf)
. Indeed they say without loss of generality we may assume that our irreducible representations are unitary: I know that irreducible reps of finite groups are equivalent to unitary reps, but I don’t see how we can say that the sum of the trace norms of the Fourier transform invariant under changes of inner product, which would allow us to make this hypothesis that the irreducible reps are unitary.

Comment: @Hyperplane I'm not sure it does. It's going in the right direction, but all I've managed to conclude from it is that the trace is independent if there is some fixed basis orthonormal with respect to both inner products, which is trivial since in that case the inner products are equal...

Comment: @Hyperplane thanks i ended up figuring it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Hyperplane i ended up figuring this out. So recall that $\rho(h)$ is unitary wrt to the inner product $\left<u,v\right>_\rho=\sum_{g\in G}\left<\rho(g)u,\rho(v)\right>$. Now let $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for this product. Then we have
$$\operatorname{Tr}(\hat{f}(\rho)\rho(g)^\ast)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left<\rho(g)v_i,\hat{f}(\rho)v_i\right>_\rho$$
while

$$\begin{align}\operatorname{Tr}(\hat{f}(\rho)\rho(g^{-1}))&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left<v_i,\rho(g^{-1})\hat{f}(\rho)v_i)\right>_\rho \nonumber \\ &=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{h\in G}\left<\rho(h)v_i,\rho(hg^{-1})\hat{f}(\rho)v_i\right> \nonumber \\&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{h\in G}\left<\rho(hg)v_i,\rho(h)\hat{f}(\rho)v_i\right> \nonumber \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n\left<\rho(g)v_i,\hat{f}(\rho)v_i\right>_\rho\end{align}$$
as required. Invariance of the trace norm didn't have much to do with it.